# FFmpeg - Change resolution of the video with aspect ratio

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resolution, aspect-ratio

all.

How to change resolution of the video with aspect ratio with FFmpeg?

There are options 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/ffmpeg.1.html

```
       -s size
       Set frame size. The format is wxh (ffserver default = 160x128,
       ffmpeg default = same as source).  The following abbreviations are
       recognized:
```

and

```
       -aspect aspect
       Set the video display aspect ratio specified by aspect.

       aspect can be a floating point number string, or a string of the
       form num:den, where num and den are the numerator and denominator
       of the aspect ratio. For example "4:3", "16:9", "1.3333", and
       "1.7777" are valid argument values.
```

For example, I have two input videos:

- with 200*400 resolution
- with 400*700 resolution

I need to make output video with 100*200 resolution.

If I will run ffmpeg with -s 100x200, then second video will have bad aspect ratio.

How can I limit output video by width, with auto aspect ratio by height?

For example, I want specify for the output video only width 100px and ffmpeg must automatically calculate height with right aspect ratio.

For first video it will be:

200/100=2

400/2=200

Ie 100x200

For second video it will be:

400/100=4

700/4=75

Ie 100x75

Is it possible?

Comment: Interesting problem - looking at the `ffmpeg` or `ffprobe` output you notice that there is SAR and DAR (source/dest aspect ratio?). These are not the same thing. E.g. I wanted simply to fix a video with a wrong AR, so I ran `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf setdar=16/10 output.mp4`. It didn't want to allow `-c:v copy`! However, when I played the video with `mpv`, there was: `VO: [gpu] 600x480 => 768x480 yuv420p` - so it was being resized while playing! So why did this operation require recoding?

Comment: OK, if someone wants to know how to change the DAR without re-encoding: https://superuser.com/questions/907933/correct-aspect-ratio-without-re-encoding-video-file sigh.

Answer (score 27):

`ffmpeg -i <input> -vf scale=720x406,setdar=16:9 <output>`

Comment: that link is broken

Comment: For me I had to use `-vf scale=854x480,setdar=16/9`. a '/' instead of a ':'

Comment: Maybe ffmpeg has changed again, but as of September 2023, it won't accept "setdar" as an option (on Debian).

Answer (score 16):

Use magic number `-1` to resize video proportionally and `setdar` need to use slash `/` as separator not colons `:`.

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "scale=100:-1,setdar=16/9" <output>
```

the command will resize video `200x400` to `100x200` and `400x700` to `100x175` with aspect ratio `16:9`

Comment: I've read a lot where people use `-2` instead of `-1`. I couldn't find the difference.. Can you link me to any docs or article that would explain it?

Comment: @TheLebDev, `-1` will tell `ffmpeg` to automatically choose the correct height in relation to the provided width ( http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Examples-98 )

Comment: @TheLebDev -2 will ensure that the dimension is a multiple of 2. Similarly -3 will produce a dimension that's multiple of 3 and so on. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling#KeepingtheAspectRatio

Comment: Multiple of 2 is important because some video containers like `mp4` require even number dimensions

Answer (score 14):

Doesn't work with video. That page only deals with still images.

For reasons not completely understood, FFMPEG monkeys around with the Sample/Pixel Aspect Ratio to turn the video back to the original aspect ratio. For instance, if you stretch the video out twice as wide, it will make the aspect ratio 1:2, or something similar (2:1?)

Thus, if you REALLY want to stretch a video out "Stretch Armstrong" style, you need to force the SAR (Sample Aspect Ratio):

```
ffmpeg -i <something> -vf scale=iw*55:ih,setsar=1:1 ...
```

This is not really well described in the FFMPEG manual, [here's a video.stackexchange answer that puts it all in one place.](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/how-do-i-change-frame-size-preserving-width-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: As stated, the manual provided in the answer below was incorrect, and I was continuing to find information. Since found, please read the modified answer.

Answer (score 2):

Below metion both option:
with Scale:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -r 15 -s 320x240 -strict -2 destination.mp4
```

With Aspect ratio:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -r 15 -aspect 1:1 -strict -2 destination.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple command to change the resolution, but keep the original aspect:
(Change to 800 width in this example)

`ffmpeg -i ogirinal_video.gif -vf scale=800:-1 changed_resolution.gif`

Answer (score 1):

I improved this code to change aspect ratio without recoding or converting original video. Just follow this:

```
ffmpeg -i (Movie name).mp4 -c copy -r 15 -aspect 2.21 -strict -2 (out put Movie name).mp4
```

Where 2.21 mentioned there you can change to 4.3 16.9 aspect ratios as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting videos in portrait and landscape orientations with different aspect ratios, you can use the **force_original_aspect_ratio** option:

```
scale=w=100:h=200:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease
```

You can chose to decrease or increase the video size output based on aspect ratio changing the **force_original_aspect_ratio** value.

Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling