# How to stretch the width of mpv/mplayer by keeping the height of the video same

Tags: linux, video, video-processing, mplayer, mpv

I have a screen which is in portrait mode and want to play some videos on it using mpv or mplayer on just lower 70% of the screen area. But since the screen is in portrait mode the video (which is also landscape) isnt getting stretched fully width wise and only occupies the width area according to resolution of the video.
The command I tried was

```
└──╼ $ mplayer -vf scale -zoom -xy 500 out.mp4
```

The video should fill the entire width os the screen, keeping the height of the video same. The video of course would get stretched but thats ok. **Im getting blue area for video, but I want orange area for the video.**

[image]

Comment: I tried this command also but it didnt work : player -vf scale -zoom -screenw 600 -screenh 500  out.mp4    ...  Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from this post :-
[FFmpeg - Change resolution of the video with aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087249/ffmpeg-change-resolution-of-the-video-with-aspect-ratio)

Had to flip aspect ratio for my project from 16/9 to 9/16

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "scale=100:-1,setdar=9/16" <output>
```